# conduit and sockets: allow multiple connections

Tags: sockets, haskell, conduit, network-conduit

Here's some code that implements a small receiving server using `conduit`, `network-conduit`, and `stm-conduit`. It receives data on a socket and then streams it through an STM-channel to the main thread.

```
import Control.Concurrent (forkIO)
import Control.Concurrent.STM (atomically)
import Control.Concurrent.STM.TBMChan (newTBMChan, TBMChan())
import Control.Monad (void)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (MonadIO (liftIO))
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class

import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Data.Conduit
import qualified Data.Conduit.Binary as DCB
import Data.Conduit.Extra.Resumable
import Data.Conduit.Network (sourceSocket)
import Data.Conduit.TMChan (sinkTBMChan, sourceTBMChan, mergeSources)

import System.Directory (removeFile)
import System.IO

type BSChan = TBMChan ByteString

listenSocket :: Socket -> Int -> IO BSChan
listenSocket soc bufSize = do
    chan <- atomically $ newTBMChan bufSize
    forkListener chan
    return chan
  where
    forkListener chan = void . forkIO $ listen soc 2 >> loop where 
      loop = do
        (conn, _) <- accept soc
        sourceSocket conn $$ sinkTBMChan chan
        close conn
        loop

main :: IO ()
main = do
  soc <- socket AF_UNIX Stream 0
  bind soc (SockAddrUnix "mysock")
  socChan <- listenSocket soc 8
  sourceTBMChan socChan $$ DCB.sinkHandle stdout
  removeFile "mysock"
```

(In the real application, the stream of data from the socket gets merged with some others, which is why I don't handle it directly in the listener).

The problem is that, where I had expected this to stay open until the main thread is killed, instead it exits after the first message is received on the socket. I cannot work out why it does this, unless it's that the sink (on 2nd to last line) is exiting once it sees the end of the first stream of data. Can I persuade it not to do this? There's some stuff in `Conduit` about making a source resumable, but not a sink.

Comment: For future questions, please include all imports as well so that your code actually compiles. Makes it much easier to test solutions.

Comment: Minor comment, unrelated to the conduit aspect of things here: the implementation here will force connections to be accepted one at a time, instead of having a separate worker thread dedicated to each incoming connection. Is that intentional?

Comment: @shang - fair point, I've update with imports. Meant to add a gist and then link to it, but I forgot about it!

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman That is correct. I want to ensure that things are recorded in the sequence that the connections are made. In general, there won't be more than one connection being made at a time anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documention of [`sinkTBMChan`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-conduit-2.1.4/docs/Data-Conduit-TMChan.html#v:sinkTBMChan):

> When the sink is closed, the channel will close too.

So when the first socket handle closes, it causes the `Source` from `sourceSocket` to close, closing the connected sink which in turn closes the `TBMChan` which propagates to `sinkHandle` stopping the sink.

The simplest way to solve this is probably to change your `loop` into a custom source that doesn't close between connections and connect that source into the `TBMChan`.

```
listenSocket :: Socket -> Int -> IO BSChan
listenSocket soc bufSize = do
    chan <- atomically $ newTBMChan bufSize
    forkListener chan
    return chan
  where
    forkListener chan = void . forkIO $ do
      listen soc 2
      loop $$ sinkTBMChan chan

    loop = do
      (conn, _) <- liftIO $ accept soc
      sourceSocket conn
      liftIO $ close conn
      loop
```

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much what I did (see below). I've stripped `network-conduit` out entirely now and just implemented a source that doesn't close the connection.

Answer (score 5):

Coordinating shutdown of writers and readers from a channel is a non-trivial problem, but you can reuse a solution from the `pipes` ecosystem to solve this, which is to use the `pipes-concurrency` library.  This library provides several `pipes`-independent utilities that you can reuse with `conduit` libraries for communicating between readers and writers so that each side automatically correctly knows when to clean up and you can manually clean up either side as well, too.

The key function that you use from the `pipes-concurrency` library is `spawn`.  Its type is:

```
spawn :: Buffer a -> IO (Output a, Input a)
```

The `Buffer` specifies what underlying STM channel abstraction to use.  Judging by your example code, it sounds like you want a `Bounded` buffer:

```
spawn (Bounded 8) :: IO (Output a, Input a)
```

The `a` can be anything in this case, so it can be a `ByteString`, for example:

```
spawn (Bounded 8) :: IO (Output ByteString, Input ByteString)
```

The `Input` and `Output` behave like a mailbox.  You add messages to the mailbox by `send`ing data to the `Output`s and you take messages out of the mailbox (in FIFO order) by `recv`ing data from `Input`s:

```
-- Returns `False` if the mailbox is sealed
send :: Output a -> a -> STM Bool

-- Returns `Nothing` if the mailbox is sealed
recv :: Input a -> STM (Maybe a)
```

The neat feature of `pipes-concurrency` is that it instruments the garbage collector to automatically seal the mailbox if there either no readers or no writers to the mailbox.  This avoids a common source of deadlocks.

If you were using the `pipes` ecosystem you would normally use the following two higher-level utilities to read and write to mailbox.

```
-- Stream values into the mailbox until it is sealed
toOutput :: Output a -> Consumer a IO ()

-- Stream values from the mailbox until it is sealed
fromInput :: Input a -> Producer a IO ()
```

However, because the core machinery is `pipes`-independent you can rewrite equivalent `conduit` versions of these functions:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift)
import Data.Conduit
import Pipes.Concurrent

toOutput' :: Output a -> Sink a IO ()
toOutput' o = awaitForever (\a -> lift $ atomically $ send o a)

fromInput' :: Input a -> Source IO a
fromInput' i = do
    ma <- lift $ atomically $ recv i
    case ma of
        Nothing -> return ()
        Just a  -> do
            yield a
            fromInput' i
```

Then your main function would look like something like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    soc <- socket AF_UNIX Stream 0
    bind soc (SockAddrUnix "mysock")
    (output, input) <- spawn (Bounded 8)
    forkIO $ readFromSocket soc $$ toOutput output
    fromInput input $$ DCB.sinkHandle stdout
  removeFile "mysock"
```

... where `readFromSocket` would be some `Source` that reads from your `Socket`.

You can then freely write to the `output` using other sources of data, too, and not worry about having to coordinate them or dispose of the `input` or `output` properly when you are done.

To learn more about `pipes-concurrency`, I recommend reading the [official tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-concurrency-2.0.1/docs/Pipes-Concurrent-Tutorial.html).

Comment: Thanks for this, looks like a potentially nicer way to go about things. I've managed to solve the problem for the moment, but I'll have a dig through the tutorial a bit later.

Answer (score 2):

I think @shang's answer is the correct one, I'd just go a bit farther and say that the behavior of `writeTBMChan` looks like the better culprit here. I'd recommend changing it to not automatically close the `TBMChan`. A simple implementation of this idea is:

```
sinkTBMChan chan = awaitForever $ liftIO . atomically . writeTBMChan chan
```

If you use that in your program, it will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

So, here's one answer which doesn't involve creating a resumable sink. The `sourceSocket` in `network-conduit` allows a single connection, but we can implement the reconnect behaviour inside `sourceSocket` (apologies for the code, I think it needs cleaning, but at least it works!):

```
sourceSocket :: (MonadIO m) => Socket -> Producer m ByteString
sourceSocket sock =
    loop
  where
    loop = do
      (conn, _) <- lift . liftIO $ accept sock
      loop' conn
      lift . liftIO $ close conn
      loop
    loop' conn = do
      bs <- lift . liftIO $ recv conn 4096
      if B.null bs
        then return ()
        else yield bs >> loop' conn
```

One problem here is that this never exits (until the program dies). This isn't a problem in my use case, since the socket should remain listening for the life of the program.